# How to include *project root* headers compiling with GCC C++ compiler?

Tags: gcc, build, g++

How to include headers located in **project root** compiling with GCC C++ compiler?
I want to tell GCC compiler to search for some header files in **project root**.
I do NOT want to make changes in code and use relative paths in #include directives - e.g. `#include "../../myheader.h"`
I compile source code I do not own and I do not want to maintain own version.
I do NOT want to specify absolute include path e.g. `g++ -c -IC:\root_project_folder ..` for obvious reasons.
I have tried: `g++ -c -I ..`, `g++ -c -I/ ..` and `g++ -c -I"/" ..` but it does not work.

Please advise.

```
root_project_folder
|--myheader.h
  |--src_folder
    |-prog.cpp
```

Comment: What directory are you in when you issue the g++ command?

Comment: If you compile in `src_folder` then `g++ -I.. prog.cc` is correct. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d17e51b65b2cf0b) Otherwise, if you compile in `root_project_folder` then it is `g++ -I. src_folder/prog.cc`. [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afeeb1ef0f2980fb) In both cases, I would use `#include <myheader.h>`. (`#include` with double quotes, I wouldn't use if the header isn't expected in the same dir. like the source.)

Comment: Issuing the command I am in the root folder. `-I.` is the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol for the current directory is `.`.

You're looking for **`-I.`**